# How to add FragmentActivity in a view

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragmentactivity

I have android activity that shows a list of android widgets. However, i need to add google maps into that list as well.

The issue here is that since google maps is not a widget(not a subclass of view) and i need to use FragmentActivity to make this work, i have problem adding this in a layout. A layout can only add View objects correct? The google maps is working fine if i'm just showing it in an individual activity. Since i need to add this in same page with other page, how will this work?

Regards,
Dexter

Comment: you can actually add fragments (in your case MapFragment) into viewgroup. see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.app.Fragment)

Comment: I'm talking about FragmentActivity is this the same? Correct me if i'm wrong but i thought Fragment has to be inside FragmentActivity correct?

Comment: Nope, you can add fragments anywhere in the layout (no matter what activity you are using). However, if you are using support library, then yes, you have to use FragmentActivity. See here (under "programmatically add the fragment to an existing ViewGroup"), https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding